# Sync imported books WITH NOTES from iOS 9 to iOS 15

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ibook

There are imported EPUBs with hundred of notes on my iPhone 4S (iOS 9, non-upgradable). I want to import these books with their notes to my other iPhone running iOS 15. I tried various options, from iCloud Sync (not working, requires iOS 12 to sync imported books) to third-party softwares (none of them transfer notes along with the epub file). Is there any viable solution to my problem?